# Screening Market Order - Limit Order Books and Modeling

Tags: market-microstructure, limit-order-book

I am reading the paper "A statistical theory of continuous double auction". The paper can be found at,

https://www.santafe.edu/research/results/working-papers/statistical-theory-of-the-continuous-double-auctio

On page 20, section F-3 titled "Screening of the market-order rate", the author states as follows. I am trying to undestand how the relationship $d\mu = -\mu (1-\pi_0)$ is arrived at. Here $\pi_0$ is the probability of zero occupation at site with price $p$. I would imagine that this is a fairly known result in physics, or physical chemistry. I would imagine there is probably a result in eletrostatic screening or diffusion problems in the presense of barriers.

I was hoping someone could point me to references or introductory exposition of anything related to this derivation.

Thank you,

> 3. Screening of the market-order rate

> In the context of independent fluctuations, Eq. (26) implies a
> relation between the mean density and
> the rate at which market orders are screened as price increases. The
> effect of a limit order, resident in the price bin p when a market
> order survives to reach that bin, is to prevent its arriving at the
> bin at p + dp. Though the nature of the shift induced, when such
> annihilation occurs, depends 21 on the comoving frame being modeled,
> the change in the number of orders surviving is independent of frame,
> and is given by $\mu = - \mu (1 - \pi_0) = -\frac{\mu <n>}{\sigma}$. (29)